# Which multiplayer map has the Cleaver as a weapon pickup for Horde

Tags: gears-of-war-3

Which of the multiplayer maps has the cleaver as a weapon pickup for Horde mode?  I am trying to get the 40 kills needed to unlock the execution and it is very slow going waiting for a butcher.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I googled a lot and found some good tips for getting cleaver in horde for execution.

You can't have cleaver as normal pickup,you have to get it from enemies.

Btw i should also note that enemies carrying the cleaver wont spawn each time so you will need some luck to get them.

**Tips from experienced players:**

> 1. To easily unlock the execution for the cleaver, go to Horde mode, and select Drydock. The Butchers will appear on Level 2. Keep picking up the cleaver and getting kills with it to unlock its execution.
> 2. Checkout, Level 5 Horde mode.
> 3. Mercy, wave 4-5

**Monsters that carry cleaver:**

- Butchers
- Savage Theron

**Sources:**
[Source # 1](http://www.xbox360achievements.org/forum/showthread.php?t=330765)  [Source #2](http://forums.xbox.com/xbox_forums/xbox_360_games/e_k/gearsofwar3/f/310/p/94392/769576.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Having checked the weapon spawn options in multiplayer versus mode, I do not believe that it's possible to have the cleaver as a weapon pickup.

However, you do not only have to wait for a Butcher. Savage Therons also spawn in Horde mode, wielding the cleaver as their weapon.

After some digging, it is [referenced](http://www.cheatcc.com/xbox360/gearsofwar3cheatscodes.html) that Drydock is a good place to get butchers:

> To easily unlock the execution for the cleaver, go to Horde mode, and
>   select Drydock. The Butchers will appear on Level 2. Keep picking up
>   the cleaver and getting kills with it to unlock its execution.